# In Rust, how check if a generic parameter is of a specific type and cast to it

Tags: generics, rust

I have several types that implement a trait (Relation). I need to pass data between them, like `INSERT INTO FROM SELECT` from sql.

However, some times I will move data that is coming from the same type, meaning I could use a more direct way:

```
impl Relation for BTree {
    fn new_from<R: Relation>(names: Schema, of: R) -> Self {
       if of is Btree { //How do this
          //Fast path
          cast(of as Btree).clone()  //And this
       } else {
          //Generic path
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think what you really want here is [impl specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md), but that could be a long time away still. In the meantime, I would suggest finding an alternative API, where callers can decide which method to call, with the knowledge of which is faster.

Comment: And finally, I recommend profiling the code (with all optimisations enabled), so you can be certain that the "fast path" is actually faster. I have been frequently surprised to measure negligible performance difference between two functions that look completely different on the surface.

Comment: @Peter Hall How can this alternative API look?

Comment: @mamcx I think the main idea would be to provide a different method, like `new_from_btree`, which only takes `BTree` and has the optimizations for that, and then just always use the generic path in `new_from`.

Answer (score 9):

What you are trying to do should be possible using [`std::any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html). I imagine it would look something like this:

```
use std::any::Any;

trait Trait {
    fn foo<T: Trait + Any>(of: T) -> Self;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Special;

impl Trait for Special {
    fn foo<T: Trait + Any>(of: T) -> Self {
        let of_any = &of as &dyn Any;
        if let Some(special) = of_any.downcast_ref::<Special>() {
            // Fast path
            special.clone()
        } else {
            // Generic path, pretend this is expensive
            Special
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the performance of this like? T is known statically, but then we throw away the information with `&dyn`. In C++ I could be guaranteed a `is_same_v<T1,T2>` check would be resolved at compile time.

Comment: This also seems much weaker -- I can't compare if the types are the same without having an instance to take a borrow of.

Comment: @JosephGarvin it cost a virtual call but in that case it probably would be optimized by LLVM because exact type is known.